# Unknown Baseband i9300 after flashing CM11?

Tags: cyanogenmod, samsung-galaxy-s-3, custom-roms

I flashed my rooted i9300 to go from stock to CM 11. I used [TWRP twrp-2.8.6.0-i9300](http://teamw.in/devices/samsunggalaxys3internationalexynos.html)
 to flash it. Previously, I did a nandroid backup using CWM but since CWM had problems with flashing GApps, I had to switch to TWRP.

Flash successful. GApps successful. However, I have:

1. "No Service" problem
2. "Baseband Unknown" in the "About device" section
3. I have a non-blank `/efs` folder. *I read that a lot of times people have issues because the folder is empty after flashing.*

Having gone over [this XDA HOW-TO](http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s3/help-i9305/4-4-x-cm11-baseband-problem-read-t2587996), I am **guessing** that I need to flash a modem for my particular phone. I even managed to locate a [collection of modems on XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s3/general/ref-galaxy-s3-modem-radio-collection-t1740061).

But a couple of questions remain:

1. What modem do I flash? My stock was 4.2 bought in Saudi Arabia so I am guessing I will need a corresponding modem? *but I have moved to India so what modem do I use? I believe the modem suffixes like JV, etc. have importance?*
2. How do I flash that modem?

Answer (score 2):

`Official CM` uses ***open source RILs*** so these Samsung RILs won't be compatible.

[Galaxy S3 RIL + Modem CWM Flashable Collection](http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s3/general/ref-galaxy-s3-ril-modem-cwm-flashable-t2076857)

i can't test this one, but you can.

**and also, read** :

- Do not flash these zips on leaked Android 4.2 Samsung ROMs unless you
  delete the System folder inside the zip using a tool such as WinRAR.
  Otherwise you will end up with no signal and you may have to re flash
  your ROM to get the 4.2 RILs back.
- **XXEMG4** and later ***Modems will modify your efs partition***(where your phone IMEI info is) making older modems incompatible with your phone.
  In order to use older modems again you must restore an old backup of
  your efs partition. So make sure to backup your efs partition before
  you do anything.

**This is for india :**
 - ***DDEMB1***

> Android : 4.1.2 Date: 20/02/2013 Carrier-Country-Region: Unbranded -
>   India, Sri Lanka, Nepal - South Asia RIL MD5:
>   788BBF58812206981E4465966BA45BBD

Download : [Mediafire](http://www.mediafire.com/download/m5p1p0q3y9lfuh1/modem_RIL_CWM_I9300DDEMB1.zip)

and as i said, if you have an backup, goto `Recovery -> Install from Zip` and install latest `EFS` From last rom.

***P.S* : Try to flash stock rom.if this problem exist Yet, you need `z3x` Box for baseband and fix this.**

hope this helps.

Comment: Don't I need `JKEMC1 Android:4.1.2 Carrier-Country Region: Unbranded - Israel - Middle East` ?

Comment: you need for india right ? So, in your comment, this is for `Middle East`

Comment: That's the problem. The phone was bought in `Middle East` and now I am in India :-P

Comment: as i know, if `efs` doesnt work with these, you need `Z3X` box and inconvenience you with this phone :)

Comment: That's right.Option like: In `TWRP -> Backup -> Backup from Modem or Efs`.

Comment: stored under `/sdcard/TWRP/BACKUPS/<some number>/<date>/` right?

Comment: Also, do I **need** CWM or will TWRP do? The file you linked to has a "CWM" in it.

Comment: **Question 1** : yeah, thats right. Q2 : as above link say it, you need CWM.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22387/discussion-between-little-child-and-m4t).